Как на Python сделать чтобы чтобы интернет отключился и через 10 секунд включился обратно?
Как на Python сделать чтобы чтобы интернет отключился и через 10 секунд включился обратно

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Запустить скрипт, который включает сирену. Пользователь должен бежать со всех ног  к компу выдёргивать провод Интернет. Через десять секунд опять включать сирену, на этот раз на всякий случай - вдруг забудет вставить провод назад.

Ну очевидно, что выполнить какую-то консольную команду на отключение интернета. Но тут всё зависит от ОС, везде всё по-разному, так что нужно уточнять вопрос.

В качестве идеи (то есть пробуйте сами, я не хочу в новогоднюю ночь, если вдруг случится, что "всё не так однозначно", переустанавливать Windows). Идея эта не моя:
import os
import time

def disable_internet():
    os.system("netsh interface set interface 'Ethernet' admin=disable")

def enable_internet():
    os.system("netsh interface set interface 'Ethernet' admin=enable")

# Отключаем интернет
disable_internet()
print("Интернет отключен")

# Ждем 10 секунд
time.sleep(10)

# Включаем интернет
enable_internet()
print("Интернет включен")

